# how to init a array with each element holding the value different from its neighbours

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a matrix or a multiple array written in python, each element in the array is an integer ranged from 0 to 7, how would I randomly initalize this matrix or multiple array, so that for each element holds a value, which is different from the values of its 4 neighbours(left,right, top, bottom)? can it be implemented in numpy?

Comment: Do you care about precisely uniform draws from the set of arrays that have that property?

Comment: Unfortunately SO isn't a code writing service.

Comment: An aside: there's a powerful representation of this kind of probability distribution called an "undirected graphical model" or ["markov random field"](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/CVonline/LOCAL_COPIES/AV0809/ORCHARD/), that allows you to capture things like the _probability_ of adjacent cells being equal", rather than just enforcing that they're not

Comment: @DavisHerring Hi , I don't care about the precision of uniform distribution

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own matrix initializer. 
Go through the array[i][j] for each i, j pick a random number between 0 and 7. 
If the number equals to either left element: array[i][j-1] or to the upper one: array[i-1][j] regenerate it once again. 
You have 2/7 probability to encounter such a bad case, and 4/49 to make it twice in a row, 8/343 for 3 in a row, etc.. the probability dropes down very quickly. 
The average case complexity for n elements in a matrix would be O(n).

Comment: There's no need to generate a random number more than once. You can just directly choose from the set of remaining alternatives

Answer (score 0):

A simpler problem that might get you started is to do the same for a 1d array. A pure-python solution would look like:

```
def sample_1d(n, upper):
    x = [random.randrange(upper)]
    for i in range(1, n)"
        xi = random.randrange(upper - 1)
        if xi >= x:
            xi += 1
        x.append(xi)
    return x
```

You can vectorize this as:

```
def sample_1d_v(n, upper):
    x = np.empty(n)
    x[0] = 0
    x[1:] = np.cumsum(np.random.randint(1, upper, size=n-1)) % upper
    x += np.random.randint(upper)
    return
```

The trick here is noting that if there is adjacent values must be different, then the difference between their values is uniformly distributed in [1, upper)

Comment: can you describe your solution to me please?